# Passing and retrieving a URL variable

Tags: php

I am trying to pass and retrieve a variable from one page to another. When i run the page
i'm getting the error 'URL not found'. So im guessing my variable hasn't been passed to the page.

When i click on the pages edit.php and delete.php the corresponding url is being displayed. i.e edit.php?id=1, edit.php?id=2 etc.  I have tried a number of different things but can't seem to resolve this issue.

Here is the source code:

First Page (The links):

```
$ads_id = $row ["ads_id"]; //Value retrieved from database and stored in local variable

<a href="delete.php?id=' . $ads_id . '">

<a href="edit.php?id=' . $ads_id . '">
```

**edit.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$ads_id = $_GET['id'];

}
else

 {

  echo "URL not found";
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the page `edit.php?id=1` directly?

Comment: The problem is that the links are pointing to edit.php?id='1', and not edit.php?id=1. Maybe. I'm not sure if that's actually a problem.

Comment: @joeframbach I think it's just a part of PHP code. So there will be no `'` in the final HTML.

Comment: Oh I see. sam didn't provide the full code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ads_id = $row ["ads_id"]; //Value retrieved from database and stored in local variable

<a href="delete.php?id=' . $ads_id . '">

<a href="edit.php?id=' . $ads_id . '">
```

Should look like this:

```
<?php
$ads_id = $row["ads_id"]; //Value retrieved from database and stored in local variable
?>

<a href="delete.php?id=<?=$ads_id?>">

<a href="edit.php?id=<?=$ads_id?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ... you are having errors because of the single quote `'` issue ...  and since you would be adding multiple links this `php function` might help you ...

```
$ads_id = $row ["ads_id"]; //Value form database source 

echo addLink("delete.php?id={$ads_id}","Link1") , "<br />";
echo addLink("edit.php?id={$ads_id}","Link1") , "<br />";

function addLink($url,$name)
{
    return sprintf("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>",$url,$name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that it doesn't have the php opening and closing tag

it should look like

```
<?php 
$ads_id = $row["ads_id"]; //Value retrieved from database and stored in local variable
?>

<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $ads_id; ?>">

<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $ads_id; ?>">
```